# django2.1,Use mysql to custom login,MySQL: "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value"

Tags: mysql, django, authentication, django-2.1, django-login

I try to custom login Django2.1 with Mysql,and I got this error: ***Field 'id' doesn't have a default value***.But I had set ID in Aliuser is 'auto_increment' and 'not null':
[image]

Where am I wrong?By the way, it is OK with sqlite3.So weird.

This is my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class AliUser(AbstractUser):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')  # user Id
    empid = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    sso_token = models.CharField(max_length=36)  # SSO Token
    token_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Here is my backends.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import RemoteUserBackend
from naxxramas.models import AliUser as User

class AliSSOUserBackend(RemoteUserBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, userId, empId, first_name='', last_name='', email=''):
        if not userId or not empId:  # not my company user
            return None

        user = None

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(empid=empId)
            self.create_unknown_user = False
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        if self.create_unknown_user:
            user, created = User.objects.update_or_create(
                empid=empId, defaults={
                    'username': email.split('@', 1)[0],
                    'empid': empId,
                    'userid': userId,
                    'first_name': first_name or last_name or '', # first_name may be null
                    'last_name': last_name or '',
                    'email': email,
                })
            if created:
                user = self.configure_user(user)

        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

And this is my views.py,i found it may wrong at "auth_login":

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponseBadRequest

def login(request):
    sso_token = request.GET.get('SSO_TOKEN')
    next = request.GET.get('BACK_URL')

    result = get_user_info_from_sso(sso_token)   # this is a method to get my staff login information
    if not result['hasError']:
        user = json.loads(result['content'])
        user_dict = normalize_user(user)
    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('auth failed!')

    userId = user_dict.get('id')
    empId = user_dict.get('empId')
    email = user_dict.get('email')
    name = user_dict.get('name')
    realname = user_dict.get('realname')

    if userId is not None:
        user = authenticate(request, userId=userId, empId=empId, first_name=name, last_name=realname, email=email)
        auth_login(request, user)

    user.sso_token = user_dict.get('token')  # update user's token
    user.save()

    response = HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    return response
```

Comment: *I got this error: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value.But I had set ID is 'auto_increment' and 'not null'* This means that server tells about some another table. PS. Check `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, not visual representation (or in addition to).

Comment: @Akina,i have more than 20 tables in this databases,in some table,'id' is not  'auto_increment'  or even exists , do I have to change all these tables?

Comment: You must find definite table which causes the issue (does its name present in complete error message? it must, it seems) and find what is the reason of this column absence in INSERT query. I.e. you must edit not table but code.